# Trusted to make this change without review

Tags: discussion, documentation

I proposed a documentation change this morning and was surprised a little while later when I got an upvote before I got the +2 for accepted. I then looked and saw:

[image]

What makes me trusted? What am I trusted for? I'm not so sure about this. Is this basically an open invitation to make trivial formatting changes to every example in C++ and lay back and count my reps?

Comment: So I guess you did not see the top entry in the yellow box on the right ==>  Read that first.

Comment: All the details are here ^

Comment: Silver or gold tag badge in the tag you're making the change in